# Convert yyyymmddThhmmss.SSSZ format to Unix Timestmp

Tags: node.js, date

I'm using NodeJS to fetch a date from a server, but the date format is yyyymmddThhmmss.SSSZ

```
20170423T203146.000Z
```

I'm trying to convert this date string into epoch time, to easily calculate a difference between this time and the current time. (the timezone will always be UTC)

However, I could not find any possibility to parse this string, since libraries don't seem to accept this kind of date string.

Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) seems to give me correct parsed date

```
var moment = require('moment')

var date = moment("20170423T203146.052Z" , "YYYYMMDDThhmmss.SSS")
console.log(date.format("YYYY MM DD hh mm ss SSS"))
```

Output: `2017 04 23 08 31 46 052`

Comment: Thanks, that was what I searched for.

Converting this to a UNIX timestamp was easy

Answer (score 1):

you should take a look at [Moment.js String+Format + Special Format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

It seems to work very well on your time-string already:

```
const moment = require("moment");

const werner = "20170423T203146.000Z";
console.log(moment.utc(werner).format());

const epochSec = moment.utc(werner).unix();
const epochMs = moment.utc(werner).valueOf();

console.log(epochSec, epochMs);
```

Viel Erfolg ;)